# Sass mixin that references parent styles

Tags: css, sass, mixins

We can reference parent selectors using the ampersand `&` but do we have a solution for referencing parent styles?

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
@mixin copy {
    &-copy {
        @media (min-width: 300px) {
            @context; // directive doesn't exist but illustrates the point
        }
    }
}

.foo {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: red;

    @include copy;
}
```

and output:

```
.foo {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: red;
}

@media (min-width: 300px) {
    .foo-copy {
        font-size: 18px;
        color: red;
    }
}
```

I can get somewhere quite close with:

```
@mixin copy ($parent) {
    &-copy {
        @media (min-width: 300px) {
            @extend #{$parent};
        }
    }
 }

 .foo {
     font-size: 13px;
     color: red;

     @include copy(&);
 }
```

...but because Sass doesn't allow us to `@extend` an outer selector from within `@media` that won't work. It would if I wasn't using media queries however.

If Sass can't do it is it likely to be added in the future or alternatively can another CSS preprocessor do it?

Comment: maybe you can pass the class as a parameter, first thing I can think of

Comment: @marczking I've updated to show why that's not going to work in my scenario. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the ampersand, see http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand for more info

Answer (score 0):

> You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media. You may only
>   @extend selectors within the same directive.

So extending will not work in the `@media`. (Which makes sense, since what extending does is just add the class to the other class in the CSS, like:

```
.element, .the-extended-class {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

Would be interesting to see how that should work with a media query in there xD.

Anyways, you'll either have to write those CSS-rules directly or maybe there's a better idea I just can't think of atm.

The nesting you mentioned via a mixin works fine when trying it out as a pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLEROb

```
@mixin size() {
  background: blue;

  &-small {
    background: green;
    width: 100px;
  }
}

.element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  @include size;
}
```

*(I think this is not your issue, at first I thought it was)*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is you want but I found a solution maybe is usefull for you:

**SASS**

```
@mixin copy {
  @content;
  &-copy {
    @media (min-width: 300px) {
      @content;
    }
  }
}

.foo { 
  @include copy{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
.foo {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
}
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  .foo-copy {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty close! I still wish we could reference the parent styles so I could have a slightly more elegant syntax but this will do for the time being! Thanks @blonfu

Comment: Another solution might be something like this: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/9ad8d99691618b20453a577e17fff821  The problem is you can't use `@extend` inside `@media` rules